# Mercaptan Detection

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have no chemical knowledge so please forgive me, I am working on a project to replicate the Ethanethiol smell that is in natural gas. With Ethanethiol liquid 99% how can this be presented to create the same smell as natural gas. I believe 0.5 on the sales scale.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Chem SE. Take a [tour] of our site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how this site works. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As natural gas (normally) is odourless, I understand your question as to how much of ethanethiol per unit of volume is necessary to replicate the alarming odour.  *Be careful* if you want to work with these materials, for example place a bowl underneath your equipment to limit spill, use a well ventilated fume hood, wear proper safety gear and be ready to rinse the equipment with bleach prior to further cleansing (glass ware) or waste disposal (lab gants).

According to [this overview](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/11460.pdf), ethanethiol is not the only mercaptan deployed in industry for this purpose, and sometimes these thioethers are blend with analogues or sulfur free compounds.  CFR 29 1910 (b) 1 [mentioned here](http://www.puc.state.nh.us/Safety/EducationAndTraining/NEPSR%20Oct%202014/8%20Burnell,%20LP%20Gas%20Odorization%20Testing.pdf) (page 2) requires 1 pound ($\pu{0.45 kg}$) of ethanethiol per 10000 gallons ($\pu{37.8 m^3}$) of *liquified* natural gas (LPG).

In NCBI's library, a [dedicated entry](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK201325/) for this compound provides some spread of "discomfort" if ethanethiol is present in air at a concentration of $4$ to $\pu{112 ppm}$ (or, $\pu{mg/m^3}$), and mentions as "level of distinct odor awareness (LOA) [...] $\pu{1.4E-4 ppm}$".